# Analysis Services Cube

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube

I am trying to understand the concept of an Analysis Services Cube.  Please see the DLL below (Dim is short for Dimension):

```
    CREATE TABLE DIMCustomer (ID INT identity, Name varchar(100), primary key (ID))
    CREATE TABLE DIMSupplier (ID INT identity, Name varchar(100), primary key (ID))
    CREATE TABLE DIMSalesman (ID INT identity, Name varchar(100), primary key (ID))
    CREATE TABLE DIMDeliveryDriver (ID INT identity, Name varchar(100), primary key (ID))
    CREATE TABLE DIMDate (ID INT identity, month varchar(100), day varchar(100), year varchar(100), primary key (ID))
CREATE TABLE FactTable (CustomerID int, SupplierID INT, SalesmanID INT, DeliveryDriverID int, DateID INT)
```

Is this an example of scenario that supports a five dimensional cube? (because the fact table contains five foreign keys (CustomerID, SupplierID, SalesmanID and DeliveryDriverID).

Comment: Yes...and No. You would technically be able to drill down all these attributes given you have set up the relationships correctly. Having said that, analysis is done on measures, which you don't seem to have at this moment. What kind of analysis(Sum/Count/Average..etc) are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

An OLAP cube is a technology that stores data in an optimized way to provide a quick response to various types of complex queries by using dimensions and measures.
OLAP cubes can be considered as the final piece of the puzzle for a data warehousing solution. The useful feature of an OLAP cube is that the data in the cube can be contained in an aggregated form.

In your case if you can include sales amount in facts table, it is possible to create sales summary handled by customer, supplier, salesman, delivery driver etc.

Suggest to read this for beginner level understanding with a sample:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/658912/Create-First-OLAP-Cube-in-SQL-Server-Analysis-Serv

Answer (score -1):

You'd get a count measure for free in ssas for the measure group which may suffice for prototyping but,agreed,where are the other facts?

Comment: I do not understand your answer.  Could you elaborate? Thanks.  Is this more of a comment?

Comment: When you create a measure group you are automatically given a measure with an aggregation type of Count.

Answer (score -2):

With this relational database schema, you'll be able to create a basic cube with 5 dimensions and 1 fact table.

The potential problem is that your fact table has no fact, I'd expect something such as salesAmount or another numeric value in your fact. At the moment your fact is a factless fact. Factless fact are a great way to model use relations between dimensions but it's usually not what you try to do in the first hours of cube design.